# How to set the font, type, and size of a String when printing to the console?

Tags: java, string, fonts

So I am a very new Java programmer attempting to create an ASCII art image using loops and I am wondering how I can change the font type, and if I am required to use a Font object, this is the object i would use

```
Font myFont = new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN, 6);
```

Seeing as I created the ASCII art using Courier New size 6, I would like to make sure that the output shown on the user's screen will also be Courier new size 6. How would I be able to do this in the code itself?

Comment: what do you mean with "the user's screen"? Is this a console application (if so, you don't get to say which fonts should be used. ANSI can do color codes, but has no idea what a font is), or is this a GUI application where you control the fonts?

Comment: It will only be viewed from the console of an IDE, such as Eclipse. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: you can't control fonts in console output.

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing to System.out on the console, you can't specify the font. In that case the font is specified by the console itself.

The Font object referred to in the OP is used for GUIs like AWT, Swing, SWT or JavaFX. If you're creating a GUI then you can specify the font with the code snippet in the OP. You would use the font on, say for example, a JLabel or JButton in swing.

If you're wanting to create ASCII art in swing, then you could set the specified font on a JTextArea. Search the [JTextArea API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) for setFont.